# Pandas: avoid using for loop in this example

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe below and a function below that takes a string as input and run `group by` the dataframe based on the string input. Right now, I am just using a loop to iterate over a list of strings to run the function one by one.

My question is that how do I improve performance, make below more efficient and avoid using a for loop, as it is slow?

I want to use `apply` and this would generate multiple dataframes but I do not how and how to store them into the dictionary structure that I use below.

**Update: my actual function doesn't just do groupby, as it performs a lot of other operations after groupby. My actual dataframe also has a lot of other columns. For simplicity, I am not showing them here**

`df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'key1':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],'key2':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],'key3':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]})`

```
def processing(df,grpId):
     df_res= df.groupby([grpId]).agg({'y':'sum'}) 
     return df_res

df_dict = dict()
for i in ['key1','key2','key3']:
        df_dict [i]= processing(df,grpId= i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `melt` then `pivot_table`

```
out = df.melt('y').pivot_table(index='variable',columns='value',values='y',aggfunc='sum')
out.loc['key1']
Out[13]: 
value
1     3.0
2     7.0
3    11.0
4    15.0
5    19.0
Name: key1, dtype: float64
```

Or `melt` with `groupby`

```
out = df.melt('y').groupby(['variable','value'])['y'].sum()
out
Out[17]: 
variable  value
key1      1         3
          2         7
          3        11
          4        15
          5        19
key2      1        25
          2        30
key3      1        15
          2        40
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. My actual function is a lot more complicated and it doesn't just do groupby. It performs many different operations over the dataframe after groupby. And the dataframe actually many other columns.

Answer (score 2):

@BENY is on the right track with melt.  I think melting your dataframe should reduce the number of times you need to group.

```
df_in = df.melt('y')
group_in = ['variable', 'value']
def processing(df,grpId):
     df_res= df.groupby(grpId).agg({'y':'sum'}) 
     return df_res

processing(df_in, group_in)
```

Output:

```
                y
variable value    
key1     1       3
         2       7
         3      11
         4      15
         5      19
key2     1      25
         2      30
key3     1      15
         2      40
```

Comment: I am curious how does it know what variable i want to groupby in your answer?  Because in my actual dataframe, there are other columns that i do not want to groupby.

Comment: You'll need to melt the dataframe correctly.  Look at pd.DataFrame.melt and play that that function to determine the correct way to melt the dataframe.   'variable' and 'value' are default namings from melt, however you can rename those using melt parameters.  However, I think you can see rudimentary how we reduced the number of loops by making the dataframe long and grouping differently.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'key1':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],'key2':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],'key3':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]})

def processing(grpId,df=df):
    df_dict2[grpId] =  df.groupby([grpId]).agg({'y':'sum'}) 

df_dict2 = dict()
ss = [*map(processing, ['key1','key2','key3'])]
df_dict2
    
{'key1':        y
 key1    
 1      3
 2      7
 3     11
 4     15
 5     19,
 'key2':        y
 key2    
 1     25
 2     30,
 'key3':        y
 key3    
 1     15
 2     40}
```

It can be realized by using global variables and map function.